# how to return NULL for double function with Intel C compiler?

Tags: c, null, intel

I have some code that I am porting from an SGI system using the MIPS compiler. It has functions that are declared to have double return type. If the function can't find the right double, those functions return "NULL"

The intel C compiler does not like this, but I was trying to see if there is a compiler option to enable this "feature" so that I can compile without changing code. I checked the man page, and can't seem to find it.

Thanks

Example of the code that currently exists, and works fine with MIPS

```
 double some_function(int param){
     double test = 26.25;
 if(param == 10){
    return test;
 }
 return (NULL);
 }
```

the intel compiler complains:
error: return value type does not match the function type

Comment: "null" is not a possible value for a double type.

Comment: What exact error message are you getting? NULL should be an integer constant with the value 0, which should convert implicitly to a double (even though it's a bad idea -- NULL should be reserved for pointers).

Comment: One thing I would check is what does code that call `some_function` do?  Does it check for a NULL return?  Or does it just operate on the return as if it's a valid double?

Comment: @JerryCoffin - since this is C, it's legal for `NULL` to be defined as `(void *)0` which would prevent it from being converted to a double.

Comment: I just checked, and the calling functions just use it as if it is a valid double (in an if statement)

Comment: Can I define NULL like that in a #define statement? Probably not, eh?

Comment: @R. Samuel: Oops, didn't notice that; you're quite right.

Comment: @Derek: In theory you're not supposed to. In fact, you probably can, though you'll want to `#undef NULL` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I just checked, and the calling functions just use it as if it is a valid double (in an if statement)

I would just modify the function to `return 0;` instead of `return NULL;`

Comment: It is clear that I could do this, I was just searching for some compiler flag or something like, as someone mentioned, the NaN type flags, that would allow a return type of NULL so that the code is consistent across platforms

Comment: @Derek: Changing the `NULL` to `0` in that context (returning a `double`) will be a no-op on the original platform, so you can still use the same code in both places (it's only working now because that platform happens to define `NULL` as `0`, whereas the new one defines it as `(void *)0`).

Answer (score 3):

There might be a "NaN" (not a number) capability, via compiler options.  But that still won't be a null.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a compiler option, but you could `#define NULL 0` to (in theory) get the desired effect.

Comment: While that's correct and probably a pragmatic solution, *if* the OP is already going to modify the source code, he could just as well do the proper modifications. That would mean modifying the particular function in question, so that it will return only sane values. `NULL` -- which is meant for pointer types -- definitely isn't one of them.

Comment: also true, and i'm trying to avoid it so the code will be consistent on both systems

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they don't return pointer-to-double? A NULL double is meaningless, since zero is a valid value for double.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` doesn't necessarily have a special meaning when it is returned from a function.  If you want to indicate that a function did not complete successfully, the common technique is to return some value that would never be returned under normal circumstances.  Usually, this means returning an invalid value.  When a function returns a pointer, it often uses `NULL` as a return value signaling an error since a `NULL` pointer is rarely a value that the user would expect the function to return.

The constant `NULL` only has meaning in the context of pointers, and since you are returning a scalar value the compiler is griping at you about using `NULL`.  Instead of returning `NULL`, find some value that could never be a valid return value and use it as your error indicator.  To make it more clear what you are doing, alias that value with a constant using `#define AN_ERROR_OCCURED <<someval>>` to avoid using "magic numbers".

Another common way to do it is to use the `errno` global ([see errno.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)).  If your function encounters an error, set `errno` to some non-zero value before returning.  The code calling your function will then can check for and handle errors using something like `if (errno) {...}`.

Yet another method is to have the function return zero if successful and a non-zero error code otherwise.  If the user needs to get data back from the function, an extra "return buffer" pointer would have to be passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will just use #ifdef INTEL for a compiler flag, and define the return as zero for that compile time option. Kind of a pain, but seems to be the best way.

Comment: It isn't the best - returning zero explicitly is.

Comment: Not when I have to maintain compatability with the other system, which is actually the baseline, and it works on that system